# How are templates in RazorEngine cached?

Tags: razor

When you call `RazorEngine.Razor.Compile()`, where is the compiled template stored?

Is it available after the programs been restarted? If there is a memory shortage, will it be dumped?

I am using `RazorEngine` in an [ASP.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASP.NET) ([MVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASP.NET_MVC_Framework)) project. Will the precompiled templates be available after the application restarts?

Would it make more sense for me to store them in the `HttpContext.Cache`?
If I did, then would it make more sense to use a different function (other than `Compile`) that bypasses the internal cache? Is there a way to execute an `ITemplate` and just pass it a model?

Does `RazorEngine.Razor.Parse()` do any caching? Or is the template recompiled each time?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Currently, after the RazorEngine compiles the templates, they are loaded into memory. These assemblies persist in memory only and do not continue beyond the lifetime of the application.

I am considering adding in support for compiling these assemblies to files, but that'll be a future version.

If you call `Razor.Parse` and pass in a name for the template, it will attempt to

1. Check the cache of in-memory assemblies for an assembly with the same name.
2. Invalid the cache of the content of the template has changed.
3. Cache the newly compiled template.

Comment: Thank you so much for answering my question. I dont know why I never saw this. So if and only if I pass a name to Razor.Parse and the template is identical to the previous time I called Razor.Parse with the same name. Then it will use the cached assembly instead of creating a new one?

Comment: @Rabbi Yes, this is how it works. When passing in a name of the template, we grab the hashcode of the template content and store that in the memory cache alongside the dynamically compiled type. Next time you call it, if the hashcode of the template string has not changed, we can freely instantiate the template type and execute it. If not, we invalidate the existing type in the cache and recompile base on the new template content.

Comment: FYI, this is not how it works in the current RazorEngine.  Profilling showed Razor.Parse causing 2 second delays each web call.  Switching it out with Razor.GetTemplate(); Razor.Run(); correctly triggered the caching for us.

Comment: Can you give an example of your original call to `Razor.Parse`?

Comment: The only way I could get any benefit from caching is by calling Compile() and then Parse(). However, the speed increase is marginal at best. Did you ever get this to work?

Comment: The trick is to call Compile() once, then Run() multiple times, not Parse(). Parse() was expensive but Run() was cheap.

Comment: I can confirm that repeated calls to Parse() with the cache item name provided does speed things up.

[Here is a quick 'n dirty LinqPad script](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzBSZ1xo5My0VUFJTHhHREZubDg/edit?usp=sharing) demonstrating as such.  Also, I reflected the libary (v3.4.1) and the Parse overload accepting the cache name does first do a lookup before compiling.

Comment: @DavidPeters looks like access to the script is restricted. Can you provide the code some other way? Thank you

Answer (score 7):

I've got this to work with RazorEngine 3.4.1.0, installed late Jan 2014.

The key is to call the expensive `Razor.Compile(content, name)` to put the template into cache, then call the cheap `Razor.Run(name, model)` to execute the template.

Remember that reading template content might be expensive -- say, involving a read from disk -- so my solution only gets template content once. This might be *too much* caching for you, so careful!

Here's the `RenderPartial` method I use inside a custom `TemplateBase<T>` subclass. It runs very quickly for multiple calls to the same template.

```
public abstract class SqlTemplate<T>: TemplateBase<T>
{
    public string RenderPartial(string templateName, object model = null)
    {
        // loading a template might be expensive, so be careful to cache content
        if (Razor.Resolve(templateName) == null)
        {
            // we've never seen this template before, so compile it and stick it in cache.
            var templateContent = GetTemplateContent(templateName);
            Razor.Compile(templateContent, templateName);
        }

        // by now, we know we've got a the template cached and ready to run; this is fast
        var renderedContent = Razor.Run(templateName, model); 
        return renderedContent;
    }

    private string GetTemplateContent(string templateName)
    {
        ... your implementation here
    }
}
```

You also need to tell Razor to use this base class `(SqlTempalte<T>)` which you can do like this, by calling `RazorEngineConfigurator.Configure()`;

```
public static class RazorEngineConfigurator
{
    private static bool configured = false;

    public static void Configure()
    {
        if (configured) 
        {
            return;
        }

        var templateConfig = new TemplateServiceConfiguration
        {
            BaseTemplateType = typeof(SqlTemplate<>), 
            EncodedStringFactory = new RazorEngine.Text.RawStringFactory()
        };

        RazorEngine.Razor.SetTemplateService(new TemplateService(templateConfig));

        configured = true;
    }
}
```

Couldn't have done it without [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11798922/6722) -- why not give that one an up-vote, too? :)

---

Edit - If you need to perform caching in a more granular way, you'll need to use a different approach using `RazorEngineTemplateService` and `ITemplateResolver`.

Here's a piece of starter code;

```
    public static RazorEngineTemplateService CreateService(ITemplateResolver resolver, ICollection<string> namespaces)
    {
        Check.IsNotNull(resolver, "resolver");
        var config = new TemplateServiceConfiguration();
        config.BaseTemplateType = typeof(PlainTextTemplate<>);
        config.EncodedStringFactory = new RazorEngine.Text.RawStringFactory();
        config.Resolver = resolver;
        config.Namespaces = new HashSet<string>(namespaces);

        var service = new RazorEngineTemplateService(config);
        return service;
    }
```

`ITemplateResolver` turns template names into template contents, so you can implement, eg, a `CachedFileTemplateResolver` which loads cached content from disk.

Comment: How would I invalid the cache without restarting the app?

Comment: This solution won't do it for you, I'm afraid. I had to create my own little system for this which uses the RazorEngine.Templating.ITemplateResolver class to get template content. I've added some starter code to the bottom of my answer in case this helps you along the right path.

Comment: So do you basically need to put filewatchers on the templates on disk to invalidate the cache and recompile them on the fly? Is there anything built in already, or do I need to roll this myself?

Comment: This is a fairly old answer and I know the interfaces have changed. IIRC this was for v2.4.2 (real guess!) but if nothing has changed in this area, then you can either use a file watcher or just check the last modified date of the file before serving back a template. IIRC the big hit is parsing the template, not loading it, but the performance characteristics of your app will suggest the right approach.